# Access VBA Export to Excel with Formats

Tags: vba, ms-access, sharepoint-2010, export-to-excel

I have Access 2010 linked to some views of a SharePoint 2010 list. The users decided they wanted to change some of the People Picker fields to enable multi-select. This broke the Access automation that I built for reporting.

The issue is when the VBA calls

```
 DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet
```

What I get in these fields in Excel is

```
 ID | LOB Exec
 1  | 16; 235
```

When I view the query results in Access I get

```
 ID | LOB Exec
 1  | Last, First M, Last, First M
```

For my report obviously they want the latter. If I select Export then Excel the prompt asks if I want to Save with formats. When I do that I get the results I need. I cannot use a saved export procedure because multiple users export to multiple Excel files so I have to be able to tell the export VBA which file to export to.

Any ideas how to duplicate this action with VBA would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So you want to export from Access to Excel, and have it "Save with formats" automatically?  Is that it?

Comment: Wouldn't the Macro action "ExportWithFormatting" do what you want?

Comment: The issue with that is the macro will not see the file name selected in the FileDialog in the VBA. I think I would have to create temp table and run some code from there. Let me try it and I will let you know.

Comment: It seems that the VBA equivalant to ExportWithFormatting is DoCmd.OutPutTo and using acFormatXLSX as the type. Thanks Ann.

Comment: So an odd issue with this - TransferSpreadsheet adds a new tab OutputTo creates a new file. That isn't going to work. I need something that seems to be in the middle of these two.

Comment: In the end I had to export the data using the OutPutTo method to two extra Excel files. From there I updated the VBA in my Excel template to copy the data into new tabs and then delete the extra files. This adds extra time to the process but at least it works.